# What does Control key do, other than its usage in terminal and right click?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, terminal

So far I have been using control key to:

- Send control commands to terminal
- Occasionally do right click

Does the key have any other function?

Comment: http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The <kbd>Control</kbd> key is used as a modifier for various purposes in different applications. In OS X, it is also used for Emacs bindings supported in many applications.

The [Apple HIG (Human Interface Guidelines)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/KeyboardShortcuts/KeyboardShortcuts.html) that is recommended for application developers discourages the use of the <kbd>Control</kbd> key (the closest equivalent to the <kbd>Control</kbd> modifier key in Windows is the <kbd>Command</kbd> key on OS X):

> **As much as possible, avoid using the Control key.** Because the Control key is already used by some of the universal access features—as well as in Cocoa text fields where Emacs-style key bindings are often used—it should be used as a modifier key only when necessary.

Here are some examples of shortcuts from [Apple's KB on OS X keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343):

> #### **Sleep and shutdown shortcuts with <kbd>Control</kbd>**
>
> <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-power button    Force your Mac to restart
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Media Eject</kbd>  (⏏)    Show restart/sleep/shutdown dialog
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Media Eject</kbd>  (⏏)    Quit all applications (after giving you a chance to save changes to open documents), then restart the computer
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Media Eject</kbd>  (⏏)    Quit all applications (after giving you a chance to save changes to open documents), then shut down the computer
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Media Eject</kbd>  (⏏)    Put all displays to sleep
>
> #### **Finder shortcuts with <kbd>Control</kbd>**
>
> <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>      Get Summary Info
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>      Open the folder that contains the current folder in a new window
>
> #### **Application and other OS X shortcuts with <kbd>Control</kbd> (may not work in some applications)**
>
> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>      Move to beginning of line/paragraph
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>      Move one character backward
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>     Delete the character in front of the cursor
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>     Move to end of line/paragraph
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>     Move one character forward
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>     Delete the character behind the cursor
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>      Delete from the character in front of the cursor to the end of the line/paragraph
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>      Center the cursor/selection in the visible area
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>      Move down one line
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>      Insert a new line after the cursor
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>      Move up one line
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>      Transpose the character behind the cursor and the character in front of the cursor
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>      Move down one page
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>      Move focus to the next grouping of controls in a dialog or the next table (when Tab moves to the next cell)
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>      Move focus to the previous grouping of controls
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>      Toggle full keyboard access on or off
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>      Move focus to the menu bar
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>      Move focus to the Dock
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>      Move focus to the active (or next) window
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>      Move focus to the previously active window
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>      Move focus to the toolbar.
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>      Move focus to the first (or next) panel
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>      Move focus to the previous panel
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>      Temporarily override the current keyboard access mode in windows and dialogs
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>      Move to the status menus in the menu bar
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Comma</kbd> (,)      Decrease screen contrast
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Period</kbd> (.)      Increase screen contrast
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>       Capture the screen to the Clipboard
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>      Capture a selection to the Clipboard
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>     Copy the formatting settings of the selected item and store on the Clipboard
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>     Display the definition of the selected word in the Dictionary application
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>      Apply formatting settings to the selected object (Paste Ruler Command)
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>       Move focus to another value or cell within a view, such as a table
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>       Move focus to another value or cell within a view, such as a table
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>       Move focus to another value or cell within a view, such as a table
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>       Move focus to another value or cell within a view, such as a table
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Space bar</kbd>      Toggle between the current and previous input sources
>   <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Space bar</kbd>      Toggle through all enabled input sources
>
> #### **Universal Access shortcuts with <kbd>Control</kbd>**
>
> <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>      Open VoiceOver Utility (if VoiceOver is on)
>   <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>      Display VoiceOver menu (if VoiceOver is on)
>   <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Semicolon</kbd> (;)      Enable/disable VoiceOver Control <kbd>Option</kbd>-lock
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>      Invert/revert the screen colors (OS X Lion or earlier)
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Comma</kbd> (,)      Reduce contrast (OS X Lion or earlier)
>   <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Period</kbd> (.)      Increase contrast (OS X Lion or earlier)

Comment: No page up key shorcut really?  Control-Command-F which does fullscreen is probably the most useful shorcut that involves the Contorl key.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it is a level 3 modifier key. You could have a look at what it does if you show the virtual keyboard. It also gives you some more [combinations of shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343).

Comment: WHat is a "evel 3 modifier key"?

Comment: modifier keys are keys such as Shift Ctrl Alt etc. wich add extra functions to the normal letter keys. have a look http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key

Comment: Does it mean Control key does nothing else, because virtual keyboard shows no difference when control is pressed?

Comment: No, it definitly has some other functions currently i'm not on my mac so i can't give you a real example. But here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key you see some combos listed. Under Mac OS X, the Control key allows the use of Emacs-style key combinations in most text entry fields. For example, Ctrl-A moves the caret to the start of the paragraph, Ctrl-L vertically centers the current line in the editing field, Ctrl-K cuts text to the end of the line to a kill ring separate from the normal clipboard, etc.